# Monit and MySQL/MariaDB Checksum

Tags: mysql, mariadb, monit, checksum

I have Monit monitoring MariaDB but when a minor MariaDB update is rolled out Monit fails to monitor as the Checksum has changed:

```
Checksum failed Service mysql_bin 

Description: checksum failed, expected af2e102140d77547325043f7455bf066 got 31504246e59e43692b6b4979b2664ab8
```

This is my MariaDB conf:

```
check process mysqld with pidfile /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
   group database
   group mysql
   start program = "/etc/init.d/mariadb start"
   stop  program = "/etc/init.d/mariadb stop"
   if failed host localhost port 3306 protocol mysql with timeout 15 seconds for 3 times within 4 cycles then restart
   if failed unixsocket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock protocol mysql for 3 times within 4 cycles then restart
   if 5 restarts with 5 cycles then timeout
   depend mysql_bin
   depend mysql_rc

 check file mysql_bin with path /usr/sbin/mysqld
   group mysql
   include /etc/monit/templates/rootbin

 check file mysql_rc with path /etc/init.d/mariadb
   group mysql
   include /etc/monit/templates/rootbin
```

The only way I know to monitor the service again is to reboot the server, is there a way to rebuild the checksum automatically or get Monit to ignore the checksum?

Log:

```
[2024-02-10T06:45:50+1100] error    : 'mysql_bin' checksum failed, expected b9bb633ea538cdb7bb39b956d6d3601d got afc49fc5a024a4f7473670a81d23e539
[2024-02-10T09:09:01+1100] info     : Monit daemon with pid [1566] stopped
[2024-02-10T09:09:01+1100] info     : 'syd5.mydomain.com' Monit 5.31.0 stopped
with http interface at [localhost]:2812
[2024-02-10T09:09:24+1100] info     : 'syd5.mydomain.com' Monit 5.31.0 started
[2024-02-10T09:23:28+1100] error    : 'mysqld' process is not running
[2024-02-10T09:23:28+1100] info     : 'mysqld' trying to restart
[2024-02-10T09:23:28+1100] info     : 'mysqld' start: '/etc/init.d/mariadb start'
[2024-02-10T09:25:28+1100] info     : 'mysqld' process is running with pid 3715
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting only `monit`?

Comment: Yes I tried Monit restart but the Monit log still says the checksum has failed for mysql_bin

Comment: Show the logs, including checksum errors and monit restarts.

Comment: I have added some of the log

Comment: the log doesn't show checksum failure after the restart

Comment: ok so what is the fix?

Answer (score 0):

A restart/reload of monit should rebuild the used checksum (see also [Monit complains of checksum failure after MariaDB reinstall and upgrade to newer version](https://serverfault.com/questions/1148845/monit-complains-of-checksum-failure-after-mariadb-reinstall-and-upgrade-to-newer)).